# inside update panel of Content page jquery tooltip position error

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery, ajax

I am facing problem in Jquery tooltip.

I m using ASP.Net.
Inside content page i m using Gridview and on mouse over of label i m showing tooltip.

I m using jquery tool to show the information.

Its working Fine but the tooltip position is not changing according to the position of the mouse.

Its showing the changing information in a single position.

I ve tried to check the width and height and all those things.

Actually it was working fine when it was normally without update panel.

But after using inside update panel its giving such error.

so please anybody  Help me as soon as possible.

Thanking you in Advance.
Umakanta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ve solved this problem making the Id different in the gridview.

Now  its working fine.........